# How to achieve multi tenancy in apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, multi-tenant

I need to create processes groups for two customer in same apache nifi server, but they can have access only to their designated process groups and as a admin I need to manage both of the process groups.Is there any nifi native solution for this? Kindly help.

Looked for settings and permissions in Nifi but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the Admin Guide in the NiFi Docs (accessible here [1] and in the Help section of a running NiFi instance) there is a section on setting up multi-tenant authorization [2].

[1] https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html

[2] https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#multi-tenant-authorization